# Add a serial column based on a sorted column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that has one column with unordered value. I want to order this column descending and add a column to record its order. My SQL code is:

```
select *
into newtable
from oldtable
order by column_name desc;

alter table newtable add column id serial;
```

Would this implement my goal? I know that rows in PostgreSQL have no fixed order. So I am not sure about this.

Comment: Please don't use `select .. into` to create a new table. It's an old and deprecated syntax. Use standard SQL instead: `create table ... as select ...`.

Comment: Just do a simple test and you'll have the answer. So far I don't see issues with your code.

Comment: What problem are you _really_ trying to solve? The new column can get "unordered" as well (you _could_ do that without creating a new table btw).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the suggestion. After the new column is created, I can select the top n values fast. I can just use where id<=n to select the top n value. Or I have to use order by column_name desc limit n every time I need to select the top n values. And my table has millions of rows.

Comment: @vyegorov Yes. I tested and found it's OK. I just want to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: @vyegorov: A lot of operations have no guaranteed ordering, but still come back with the "expected" result 98% of the time. I wouldn't rely on test results in a case like this.

Comment: @NickBarnes, my point was: test the code and see what it does, then come back if there're mismatches with OP expectations. Otherwise I am fully aware of the un-ordering point here, I upvoted a_horse_with_no_name's comment.

Comment: @Ben: Create an index on `(column_name DESC)`, and try your `LIMIT n` query again.

Comment: @NickBarnes Yes. This is a reliable way. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than (ab)using a `SERIAL` via `ALTER TABLE`, generate it at insert-time.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (id serial unique not null, LIKE oldtable INCLUDING ALL);

INSERT INTO newtable 
SELECT nextval('newtable_id_seq'), *
FROM oldtable
ORDER BY column_name desc;
```

This avoids a table rewrite, and unlike your prior approach, is guaranteed to produce the correct ordering.

(If you want it to be the PK, and the prior table had no PK, change `unique not null` to `primary key`. If the prior table had a PK you'll need to use a `LIKE` variant that excludes `constraints`).

Comment: Wow. Great. I never saw the nextval function before. So much I need to learn.

Comment: @Ben You don't have to use `nextval` explicitly anyway; you can instead omit `id` from the inserted columns by naming all the others. This was just easier to write when I didn't know the column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a new table, sorted based on the column you want to use:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS
SELECT * FROM oldtable
ORDER BY column_name desc;
```

Afterwards, since you want to order from the largest to the smallest, you can add a new column to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE newtable ADD COLUMN id serial unique;
```